# Instantiate a module number of times based on a parameter value in Verilog

Tags: module, verilog

Assume we have the following arbitrary parameterized module

```
module module_x #(parameter WIDTH = 1) (in_a, in_b, out);
    input [WIDTH - 1] in_a, in_b;
    output out;

    // Some module instantiation here
endmodule
```

How do I instantiate another based on the value of WIDTH ? like if it's 5 I instantiate it 5 times on each bit, is it possible to do this in Verilog ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generate statements are a common approach to this: [Section 27 page 749 of IEEE 1800-1012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf).

A quick example :

```
logic [WIDTH-1:0] a;
logic [WIDTH-1:0] b; 

genvar i;
generate
for(i=0; i<WIDTH; i++) begin
  module_name instance_name(
    .a(a[i]), 
    .b(a[i])
  );
end
endgenerate
```

As @toolic has pointed out instance arrays are also possible, and simpler.

```
logic clk;
logic [WIDTH-1:0] a_i;
logic [WIDTH-1:0] b_i; 

module_name instance_name[WIDTH-1:0] (
 .clk ( clk ), //Single bit is replicated across instance array
 .a   ( a_i ), //connected wire a_i is wider than port so split across instances
 .b   ( b_i )
);
```

Comment: What would happen if we have WIDTH > input > 1 ?

Comment: @3bdalla it is my understanding that if the connected wire is wider than the port it is split and repeated to fill the array. input of 2 bits. wire 3 bits with an instance array of WIDTH 3. wire 3'bjkl would be repeated to `6'bjkljkl`, which would be split up into `jk`, `lj`, `kl` to the 3 instances. `jkl`used as place holders valid values are from `01zx`